# How to simplify if condition and foreach condition in c#.net?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, foreach, model

I have a repeating foreach condition in my controller. How can I simplify it?
I almost reach 500 lines because of this. I've been using this for  x8 each condition.

```
List<jewelry_dashboard_view_per_month> transactionmonthlynewloan = dashboardmanager.Get_MonthlyTransaction(search_branch, (monthlyonly + "01"), "N-", (monthlyonly + no_of_items), no_of_items, monthlyonly);
myNewLoanMontlyList.Add(transactionmonthlynewloan);

List<jewelry_dashboard_view_per_month> transactionmonthlyrenewal = dashboardmanager.Get_MonthlyTransaction(search_branch, (monthlyonly + "01"), "R-", (monthlyonly + no_of_items), no_of_items, monthlyonly);
myRenewalMontlyList.Add(transactionmonthlyrenewal);
```

This is the if condition

```
if (myNewLoanMontlyList[0].Count != 0)
{
    foreach (var internal_monthly_newloan_data in myNewLoanMontlyList[0].SelectMany(c => c.id_data))
    {monthly_newloan_data_ID.Add(internal_monthly_newloan_data);}

    foreach (var internal_monthly_newloan_data in myNewLoanMontlyList[0].SelectMany(c => c.debit_data))
    {monthly_newloan_data_debit.Add(internal_monthly_newloan_data);}
}
else
{
    monthly_newloan_data_ID.Add(0);
    monthly_newloan_data_debit.Add(0);
};
```

and this is the foreach condition

```
//newloan
int newloan_data_id = 0;
DateTime newloan_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((DateTime.Today).ToString());
decimal newloan_data_debit = 0;
string newloan_data_txnname = "";
string newloan_data_branchID = "";
foreach (var newloan_data in newloan)
{
    newloan_data_id = newloan_data.ID;
    newloan_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((newloan_data.Transdate).ToString());
    newloan_data_debit = Decimal.Parse((newloan_data.Debit).ToString());
    newloan_data_txnname = newloan_data.TransactionName;
    newloan_data_branchID = newloan_data.BranchID;
};
datanewloan = new transaction_details()
{
    ID = newloan_data_id,
    Transdate = DateTime.Parse(newloan_data_transdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
    Debit = Decimal.Parse(newloan_data_debit.ToString()),
    TransactionName = newloan_data_txnname,
    BranchID = newloan_data_branchID
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq`,

> [SelectMany:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) Projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>`. You need not to iterate again and add it to separate list

For your if condition look like,

```
if (myNewLoanMontlyList[0].Any())
{
    monthly_newloan_data_ID = myNewLoanMontlyList[0].SelectMany(c => c.id_data);
    monthly_newloan_data_debit = myNewLoanMontlyList[0].SelectMany(c => c.debit_data);
}
else
{
    monthly_newloan_data_ID.Add(0);
    monthly_newloan_data_debit.Add(0);
}
```

---

> [Select:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) Projects each element of a sequence into a new form. In your
> case new form is instance of `transaction_details`

Instead of for loop use Linq `.Select()`,

```
var result = newloan.Select(x => new transaction_details(){
          ID = x.ID,
          Transdate = DateTime.Parse(x.Transdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
          Debit = Decimal.Parse((x.Debit).ToString()),
          TransactionName = x.TransactionName,
          BranchID =  x.BranchID
}).LastOrDefault();
```

To get last element, I used [`LastOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault?view=netcore-3.1). You can get individual element by index or by condition.

Comment: @DamHarvey, does it answer your question?was it helpful?

Comment: cannot convert System.Collection.List<transaction_details> to transaction_details.

Comment: @DamHarvey, we can use LastOrDefault to get individual transaction_details object.You can do it with index as well. I updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

In Your scenario of `if-else` conditions:

```
if (myNewLoanMontlyList[0].Count != 0)
{
    foreach (var internal_monthly_newloan_data in myNewLoanMontlyList[0].SelectMany(c => c.id_data))
    {monthly_newloan_data_ID.Add(internal_monthly_newloan_data);}

    foreach (var internal_monthly_newloan_data in myNewLoanMontlyList[0].SelectMany(c => c.debit_data))
    {monthly_newloan_data_debit.Add(internal_monthly_newloan_data);}
}
else
{
    monthly_newloan_data_ID.Add(0);
    monthly_newloan_data_debit.Add(0);
};
```

If in the method, there is no other process after the `if-else`, you can use only `if` condition without the `else` part.

```
    if (myNewLoanMontlyList[0].Count == 0)
    {
       monthly_newloan_data_ID.Add(0);
       monthly_newloan_data_debit.Add(0);
    }

    foreach (var internal_monthly_newloan_data in myNewLoanMontlyList[0].SelectMany(c => c.id_data))
    {monthly_newloan_data_ID.Add(internal_monthly_newloan_data);}

    foreach (var internal_monthly_newloan_data in myNewLoanMontlyList[0].SelectMany(c => c.debit_data))
    {monthly_newloan_data_debit.Add(internal_monthly_newloan_data);}
```

Comment: still a long process. need a shorter one.

Comment: Optimization depends upon the logic and requirement. If some conditions are necessarily have to put, then they are must to implement. No solution to omit main `if-else`

Comment: ok2x. if there's no solution I proabably stick to if-else and foreach